# In which request event does MVC Routing occurs.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-routing, httphandler

I have gone though MVC Request life cycle and I still did not get any clarity in where the requests are routed to handlers based on registered routes.

We place MVC requests with an url it  then finds the controller and delivers the  right cshtml page. 
As the url is without any resource type, how http module events or http handlers differentiate MVC requests and passes it to the right controller.

Comment: Try google for MVC pipeline. For example [this document](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) from the ASP .Net site describes the MVC 5 pipeline. Or this [set of slides](http://www.slideshare.net/llysik/aspnet-mvc-4-request-pipeline-internals) describing MVC 4

Comment: @DanielJ.G. Thank you, the slides for MVC 4 is very detailed, thanks. Can you write this in answer section to mark it as answer.

Comment: I don't think its a request event per se. You are probably asking about the event on the HttpApplication instance. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @deostroll the link offered by danny ("set of slides") answers how routing handler is done in http modules answered my clarification.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the answer. The event you are specifically interested in was the PostRequestResolveCache which happens on the HttpApplication instance. That is where the UrlRoutingModule does most of its work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [this document](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) from Microsoft´s ASP .Net site, describing in detail the MVC 5 request lifecycle and how it IS integrated into the ASP .Net lifecycle. Some sections of the diagrams in the pdf itself link to relevant pages in the msdn.

Another good resource are [this set of slides](http://www.slideshare.net/llysik/aspnet-mvc-4-request-pipeline-internals) from Lukasz Lysic that explains in detail the request lifecycle in MVC 4.

**EDIT: I am not a fan of link-only answers, so I have added some more detail below.**

---

On your machine level web.config, you will see the [`UrlRoutingModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutingmodule.aspx) registered as an [`IHttpModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). For example, on my computer I have:

```
<system.web>
   <httpModules>
      ...
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
      ...
   </httpModules>
<system.web>
```

On the [`PostResolveRequestCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx) application event, the routing module iterates through all the routes in the [`RouteCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutingmodule.routecollection.aspx) property and searches for a route that has a URL pattern that matches the format of the HTTP request. When the module finds a matching route, it retrieves the [`IRouteHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler.aspx) object for that route. From the route handler, the module gets an [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) object and uses that as the HTTP handler for the current request (calling its `ProcessRequest` method or its async counterparts `BeginProcessRequest` and `EndProcessRequest`).

- You can check the UrlRoutingModule code [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Routing/UrlRoutingModule.cs#6c2aec1d0de60c86#references) on the Microsoft .Net Reference Source site.

In the case of an MVC application, when you add a route in `global.asax`  using the `MapRoute` extension method, an `MVCRouteHandler` is created.

- Check the `MapRoute` method in the [`RouteCollectionExtensions`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/RouteCollectionExtensions.cs) class:

  ```
  public static Route MapRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces)
  {
      if (routes == null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");
      }
      if (url == null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
      }

      Route route = new Route(url, new MvcRouteHandler())
      {
          Defaults = CreateRouteValueDictionaryUncached(defaults),
          Constraints = CreateRouteValueDictionaryUncached(constraints),
          DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary()
      };

      ConstraintValidation.Validate(route);

      if ((namespaces != null) && (namespaces.Length > 0))
      {
          route.DataTokens[RouteDataTokenKeys.Namespaces] = namespaces;
      }

      routes.Add(name, route);

      return route;
  }
  ```

So when a request is matched to an MVC route, it will be handled by an `MvcRouteHandler`. As mentioned above, the purpose of the `IRouteHandler` of a route is to get an `IHttpHandler` that will be used by the application to continue handling the request. The `MvcRouteHandler` will return an `MvcHandler` which is the entry point of the MVC-specific pipeline.

- Check the `GetHttpHandler` method of the [`MvcRouteHandler`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/MvcRouteHandler.cs) class:

  ```
  protected virtual IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
  {
      requestContext.HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior(GetSessionStateBehavior(requestContext));
      return new MvcHandler(requestContext);
  }
  ```

The MVC-specific pipeline basically starts with the `ProcessRequest` method (Or the async `BeginProcessRequest`/`EndProcessRequest`). The `MvcHandler` will get the `IControllerFactory` (By default, [`DefaultControllerFactory`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultControllerFactory.cs) will be used, unless you register your own using `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetDefaultControllerFactory` in global.asax Application_Start), use it to create the controller instance based on the current route values and start controller execution.

- Check the `ProcessRequest` method of the [`MvcHandler`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/MvcHandler.cs) class:

  ```
  protected internal virtual void ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
      IController controller;
      IControllerFactory factory;
      ProcessRequestInit(httpContext, out controller, out factory);

      try
      {
          controller.Execute(RequestContext);
      }
      finally
      {
          factory.ReleaseController(controller);
      }
  }

  private void ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, out IController controller, out IControllerFactory factory)
  {
      // If request validation has already been enabled, make it lazy. This allows attributes like [HttpPost] (which looks
      // at Request.Form) to work correctly without triggering full validation.
      // Tolerate null HttpContext for testing.
      HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
      if (currentContext != null)
      {
          bool? isRequestValidationEnabled = ValidationUtility.IsValidationEnabled(currentContext);
          if (isRequestValidationEnabled == true)
          {
              ValidationUtility.EnableDynamicValidation(currentContext);
          }
      }

      AddVersionHeader(httpContext);
      RemoveOptionalRoutingParameters();

      // Get the controller type
      string controllerName = RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");

      // Instantiate the controller and call Execute
      factory = ControllerBuilder.GetControllerFactory();
      controller = factory.CreateController(RequestContext, controllerName);
      if (controller == null)
      {
          throw new InvalidOperationException(
              String.Format(
                  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                  MvcResources.ControllerBuilder_FactoryReturnedNull,
                  factory.GetType(),
                  controllerName));
      }
  }
  ```

This should explain how incoming requests are matched to controllers in MVC. For the rest of the MVC pipeline, please check the links at the beggining of the post!